# having troubles importing counter from collections python 2.73

Tags: python, import

I have read other people have this problem to but the solutions didn`t work for me. I know for a fact im running python 2.73 and i do not have a file called collections or counter. Whenever i try to import the counter i receive this error.

```
from collections import counter
ImportError: cannot import name counter
```

any suggestions for fixing this would be great thanks!

Answer (score 4):

`Counter()` not `counter()`:

```
from collections import Counter
```